# Hosting a GitHub repo in Hostinger

Tags: python, github, hosting, web-hosting, index.html

I am using hostinger to host my local website.
In hostinger, a file must be names index to be registered as the 'home' and will be what is initially shown. At the moment, I am running my website through a local host, with an app.py. I have boostrap, and menu and layout files which are applied throughout the website, meaning I can not simply run home.html for the website. I have uploaded this git repo to hostinger, https://github.com/vishwaa-atomic/Conrad-1ptest.git, and it is deployed well. But nothing is displayed due to a lack of an index file. To bypass this I tried naming the app.py to index.py (no luck) and running an indexer script (also no luck, just displays my files). Does anyone know how to get my website to successfully display, otherwise I will have to make major changes to all the files so that I can rename home.html to index.html and hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.htaccess` file in your document root with the contents:

```bash
DirectoryIndex home.html
```

That is the standard way of configuring which file powers the home page for the Apache webserver (which is used by Hostinger and almost all companies offering shared hosting.)

When you say that you will have to make major changes to your files to change `home.html` to `index.html`, that worries me.  The file that powers your home page should never appear in your URLs.  When you link to URLs, you should link to the home directory like `<a href=/>` not to the actual home page file `<a href=home.html>`.  It sounds to me like you need to go through and change all your files anyway.

Comment: Sorry, when I meant major, I was referring to how my website builds. It uses Flask and frozen Flask, so I have things stored in blocks such as this in my layout.html,

  <div class="container">
    {% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
  </div>

If the home.html is not loading correctly, it is probably because of the blocks, so I would have to go through everything and copy the layout into individual HTML files.

Comment: Also, after adding the htaccess file, it still shows a 403 error. Can you please have a look at the repo and tell me what I could do? I am thinking of switching to Heroku, which supports Python, so I can deploy Flask.